# Get audio file from server endpoint and play in vue app

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, audio, html5-audio

We have a listing module.

In that there is an audio element for each row.

How can I get the mp3/wav from API and then correctly bind it with src of audio element?

Here is my code:
JS

```
methods:{
    playa(recording_file) => {
        try {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt')
            },
        };      
        const response = axios.post(`api/playrecfile?rec=${recording_file}`)
        const mp3 = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' })
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(mp3);//tried window.
        return url;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('play audio error: ', e)
        }
    }
}
```

HTML(cell of a row)(I can see data and checked value of meta also)

```
<div :class="classes" @click="click(data)" v-else-if="name=='Play'" title='Play'>
    <!--  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span> -->
    <audio controls :ref="'audio'+data.recording_file" v-if="meta.is_admin==1 && data.recording_filename" :src="playa(data.recording_filename)">
    </audio>
    <span v-else @click="givealert()">
        <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

PHP/Laravel

```
$out = isset($request->out) ? $request->out : "mp3";
header("Content-type: audio/x-$out");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=tuzbd.$out");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$file = base_path(). "/storage/app/recs/2019/05/03/tuzbd.mp3";
header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the Vue-JS framework but the logic in regular HTML5 would be:

**(1)** Give the audio tag an ID (*eg:* `myAudio`).

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls :ref="'audio'+data.recording_file" v-if="meta.is_admin==1 && data.recording_filename" :src="playa(data.recording_filename)">
</audio>
```

**(2)** Then directly update the audio tag's source with result of `createObjectURL`:

Using Vue-JS you want to achieve something like this:

```
methods:{
    playa(recording_file) => {
        try 
        {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                headers:    {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt')
                            },
            };      
            
            var response = axios.post(`api/playrecfile?rec=${recording_file}`)
            
            //# try reading into Blob as BINARY data (eg: raw bytes)
            //const mp3 = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' })
            var mp3 = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
            
            //const  = URL.createObjectURL(mp3);//tried window.
            //return url; //# don't Return but instead just update the audio tag's source...
            
             //# update file path for Audio tag...
            var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( mp3 );
            
            var audioObj = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            audioObj.setAttribute("src", url); //# updates the source of the Audio tag
            
            //# If you need to handle MP3 bytes... eg: read/modify/delete some ID3 metadata bytes...
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL( mp3 );
            
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
            {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
                {
                    //# access MP3 bytes here... as arraybuffer
                    bytes_mp3 = new Uint8Array( evt.target.result ); //define your "var bytes_mp3" globally (var is outside of any function)
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (e) { console.log('play audio error: ', e) }
    }
```

Where the above FileReader reads the file as a stream of bytes (since audio tag is expecting a file, meaning its just a stream of bytes regardless if data is MP3 or PDF).

Comment: What's the point in using the FileReader when you don't use the result and do `createObjectURL` in onloadend instead?

Comment: @Endless, I'm guessing your down-vote is from lack of experience working with media bytes in HTML5 environment.  At some point the asker will need bytes access, the reader is there to anticipate the next step after when the Asker responds (you just down-vote without giving them a chance to speak)... Anyways does the edit make better sense to you as to why the reader is involved (try to see bigger picture of: _"...Why are Blobs and not direct URLs involved in this"_ etc)?